# How do we play together in Dungeon Defender Eternity

Tags: dungeon-defender-eternity

We have bought 2 copies of the game on Steam.

Now we want to join the same battles.

Is that possible? 
We cant see each other in the tavern

Answer (score 1):

See http://forums.dungeondefenders2.com/showthread.php?116558-How-do-I-invite-friends-into-a-private-game

In game press F11, this'll open up the Playverse overlay.

Look through the tabs, one of them will say "Session" and to the right of it theres a magnifying glass, click that, it'll open search.

Search for your friends name, add them to a party, now start a game and they'll be prompted to join.